# How to have data compatibility in MongoDb?

Tags: mongodb

I was recently asked this question. Can some one please explain how to achieve this.

How to have data compatibility across versions in MongoDb?

Kindly reply,Thanks in advance

Comment: Please elaborate. Data compatibility between two documents in Mongo? Two collections? An external source and Mongo?

Comment: between two version of Mongodb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[setFeatureCompatibilityVersion](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/setFeatureCompatibilityVersion/) enables or disables the features that persist data incompatible with earlier versions of MongoDB.

MongoDB Release notes for each version provides detailed upgrade/downgrade instruction such as this one: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/4.0-downgrade-standalone/

Usually, you can move up and down one major release. For instance, from 4.0 you can downgrade to 3.6, but not to 3.4.